# Ненормальное поведение Хрома после добавления метода авторизации

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome

В общем, решил я выделиться (я это так называю) перед друзьями возможностями убунты и добавил метод авторизации при помощи libpam-blue, но столкнулся с проблемой, что после того, как перезагрузить ноут (или просто выйти из аккаунта и зайти), у хрома сбивается синхронизация и там приходится тоже перезаходить. В чем могут быть проблемы? В какую сторону вообще рыть?

P. S. ---

Что сделал: см. [гайд](https://www.opennet.ru/tips/1973_pam_auth_usb_bluetooth.shtml)

Что ожидаю: хром не перестает синхронизировать пароли, историю, не требует заново перелогинится при каждой перезагрузке.

Что происходит: как уже многие догадались, появляется желтый треугольник справа вверху возле имени аккаунта и сообщение о том, что нужно перелогинится. Еще выскакивает в ОС сообщение о keyring (требует ввод пароля).

Comment: наверно, вам надо подробно описать, что именно вы сделали, чего ожидаете, и что получаете в данный момент.

Comment: спасибо за интерес к вопросу. дополнил описание ошибки.